# Model Output is Nan After some iterations

Tags: python, nlp

I'm currently knee-deep in troubleshooting my Automatic Speech Recognition (ASR) model, and I've hit a roadblock. After a few training iterations, the model starts throwing NaN values, specifically in the decoder stage. My suspicion is that it's related to the MultiHeadAttention module.

I'm turning to you all for insights and guidance on two fronts:

Understanding the Issue: Any ideas on why this NaN problem might be cropping up? I've scrutinized the MultiHeadAttention module, but I might be missing something.

Prevention Strategies: How can I preemptively prevent NaN issues in the MultiHeadAttention? Are there alternative implementations worth exploring?

If anyone has encountered a similar hiccup or can offer guidance, please share your wisdom. Your help is immensely appreciated!

```
class Conv1d(nn.Conv1d):
    def _conv_forward(
        self, x: Tensor, weight: Tensor, bias: Optional[Tensor]
    ) -> Tensor:
        return super()._conv_forward(
            x, weight.to(x.dtype), None if bias is None else bias.to(x.dtype)
        )


def sinusoids(length, channels, max_timescale=10000):
    """Returns sinusoids for positional embedding"""
    assert channels % 2 == 0
    log_timescale_increment = np.log(max_timescale) / (channels // 2 - 1)
    inv_timescales = torch.exp(-log_timescale_increment * torch.arange(channels // 2))
    scaled_time = torch.arange(length)[:, np.newaxis] * inv_timescales[np.newaxis, :]
    return torch.cat([torch.sin(scaled_time), torch.cos(scaled_time)], dim=1)

class MultiHeadAttention(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, n_state: int, n_head: int):
        super().__init__()
        self.n_head = n_head
        self.query = Linear(n_state, n_state)
        self.key = Linear(n_state, n_state, bias=False)
        self.value = Linear(n_state, n_state)
        self.out = Linear(n_state, n_state)

    def forward(
        self,
        x: Tensor,
        xa: Optional[Tensor] = None,
        mask: Optional[Tensor] = None,
        kv_cache: Optional[dict] = None,
    ):
        q = self.query(x)

        if kv_cache is None or xa is None or self.key not in kv_cache:
            # hooks, if installed (i.e. kv_cache is not None), will prepend the cached kv tensors;
            # otherwise, perform key/value projections for self- or cross-attention as usual.
            k = self.key(x if xa is None else xa)
            v = self.value(x if xa is None else xa)
        else:
            # for cross-attention, calculate keys and values once and reuse in subsequent calls.
            k = kv_cache[self.key]
            v = kv_cache[self.value]

        wv, qk = self.qkv_attention(q, k, v, mask)
        return self.out(wv), qk

    def qkv_attention(
        self, q: Tensor, k: Tensor, v: Tensor, mask: Optional[Tensor] = None
    ):
        n_batch, n_ctx, n_state = q.shape
        scale = (n_state // self.n_head) ** -0.25
        q = q.view(*q.shape[:2], self.n_head, -1).permute(0, 2, 1, 3) * scale
        k = k.view(*k.shape[:2], self.n_head, -1).permute(0, 2, 3, 1) * scale
        v = v.view(*v.shape[:2], self.n_head, -1).permute(0, 2, 1, 3)

        qk = q @ k
        if mask is not None:
            qk = qk + mask[:n_ctx, :n_ctx]
        qk = qk.float()

        w = F.softmax(qk, dim=-1).to(q.dtype)
        return (w @ v).permute(0, 2, 1, 3).flatten(start_dim=2), qk.detach()


class ResidualAttentionBlock(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, n_state: int, n_head: int, cross_attention: bool = False):
        super().__init__()

        self.attn = MultiHeadAttention(n_state, n_head)
        self.attn_ln = LayerNorm(n_state)

        self.cross_attn = (
            MultiHeadAttention(n_state, n_head) if cross_attention else None
        )
        self.cross_attn_ln = LayerNorm(n_state) if cross_attention else None

        n_mlp = n_state * 4
        self.mlp = nn.Sequential(
            Linear(n_state, n_mlp), nn.GELU(), Linear(n_mlp, n_state)
        )
        self.mlp_ln = LayerNorm(n_state)

    def forward(
        self,
        x: Tensor,
        xa: Optional[Tensor] = None,
        mask: Optional[Tensor] = None,
        kv_cache: Optional[dict] = None,
    ):
        x = x + self.attn(self.attn_ln(x), mask=mask, kv_cache=kv_cache)[0]
        if self.cross_attn:
            x = x + self.cross_attn(self.cross_attn_ln(x), xa, kv_cache=kv_cache)[0]
        x = x + self.mlp(self.mlp_ln(x))
        return x


class AudioEncoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(
        self, n_mels: int, n_ctx: int, n_state: int, n_head: int, n_layer: int
    ):
        super().__init__()
        self.conv1 = Conv1d(n_mels, n_state, kernel_size=3, padding=1)
        self.conv2 = Conv1d(n_state, n_state, kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=1)
        self.register_buffer("positional_embedding", sinusoids(n_ctx, n_state))

        self.blocks: Iterable[ResidualAttentionBlock] = nn.ModuleList(
            [ResidualAttentionBlock(n_state, n_head) for _ in range(n_layer)]
        )
        self.ln_post = LayerNorm(n_state)

    def forward(self, x: Tensor):
        """
        x : torch.Tensor, shape = (batch_size, n_mels, n_ctx)
            the mel spectrogram of the audio
        """
        x = F.gelu(self.conv1(x))
        x = F.gelu(self.conv2(x))
        x = x.permute(0, 2, 1)

        assert x.shape[1:] == self.positional_embedding.shape, "incorrect audio shape"
        x = (x + self.positional_embedding).to(x.dtype)

        for block in self.blocks:
            x = block(x)

        x = self.ln_post(x)
        return x


class TextDecoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(
        self, n_vocab: int, n_ctx: int, n_state: int, n_head: int, n_layer: int
    ):
        super().__init__()

        self.token_embedding = nn.Embedding(n_vocab, n_state)
        self.positional_embedding = nn.Parameter(torch.empty(n_ctx, n_state))

        self.blocks: Iterable[ResidualAttentionBlock] = nn.ModuleList(
            [
                ResidualAttentionBlock(n_state, n_head, cross_attention=True)
                for _ in range(n_layer)
            ]
        )
        self.ln = LayerNorm(n_state)

        mask = torch.empty(n_ctx, n_ctx).fill_(-np.inf).triu_(1)
        self.register_buffer("mask", mask, persistent=False)

    def forward(self, x: Tensor, xa: Tensor, kv_cache: Optional[dict] = None):
        """
        x : torch.LongTensor, shape = (batch_size, <= n_ctx)
            the text tokens
        xa : torch.Tensor, shape = (batch_size, n_audio_ctx, n_audio_state)
            the encoded audio features to be attended on
        """
        offset = next(iter(kv_cache.values())).shape[1] if kv_cache else 0
        x = (
            self.token_embedding(x)
            + self.positional_embedding[offset : offset + x.shape[-1]]
        )
        x = x.to(xa.dtype)

        for block in self.blocks:
            x = block(x, xa, mask=self.mask, kv_cache=kv_cache)

        x = self.ln(x)
        logits = (
            x @ torch.transpose(self.token_embedding.weight.to(x.dtype), 0, 1)
        ).float()

        return logits
```